# "I said I would/will go" — which one is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, simple-past

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of “will” and “would”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/usage-of-will-and-would)

> - I said I will go.
> - I said I would go.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct but they mean different things. You might be interested in our sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2), which is about to get created. Feel free to commit and post. Thank you.

Comment: This should help you :
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/usage-of-will-and-would

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on punctuation. The first needs to be written as *I said ‘I will go’.* That shows that the speaker is reporting the actual words spoken. However, if the speaker wants to report those words indirectly, then it would appear as *I said I would go.*
That, at least, is the formal position, but, particularly in speech, you will find *I said I will go*, although it might often be as part of a longer sentence such as *I said I will go, and so I will.*