# "He promised" [...] "that he will" or "that he would"?

Tags: grammaticality

1. He promised **that he will** help me with my homework.
2. He promised **[that] he would** help me with my homework.

Which sentence is grammatically correct? I saw this debate and I genuinely don't know the answer since English isn't my first language. But I feel like the second sentence is more pleasing to hear.

Can someone help? If you have an answer can I know why that was your answer?

Comment: 1-We often skip the connecting word *that* because we understand it without saying it. 2-The two promises are very similar, so we can't say which promise he made, but *will* is more solid and *would* is more theory.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Sorry but if *that* wasn't removed, would the first sentence still be more proper?

Comment: Both sentences are good as they are, with will or would, with that or not. In everyday language, they mean the same. But to be precise, *will* predicts the future (a real promise). *Would* is a little vague, like "I did say I would help you, but I got busy," Or "I would help if you were the sort that helped me. Hah." My numbering was not matched to the examples, just separate points.

Comment: Did you *deliberately* include the (entirely optional) "subordinating conjunction" ***that*** in the first example, but NOT the second? It's semantically irrelevant, so it's distracting to have a meaningless difference between your two texts. Put it in both or neither, and/or ask a separate question about ***that*** if you don't understand the point I'm making here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isn't this against tense agreement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109916/isnt-this-against-tense-agreement) Also ["I said I would/will go" — which one is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100204/i-said-i-would-will-go-which-one-is-correct) and others.

Comment: If you use 'will', you are still expecting him to do it.