# 'Will' or 'would'?

Tags: grammar, differences, british-english

> She *has asked* Peter to bathe but he *will* not do it.

I'd like to know why we use present perfect (has asked )
and why we use (will) not (would ) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of "will" and "would"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/usage-of-will-and-would)

Comment: The tense of the verbs depends on the situation being described. I would interpret your sentence as describing a situation happening now (people at the beach?) Peter has just been asked by another person present if he will bathe, but he does not want to. If all this had happened last week, you might say "She asked (or 'had asked') Peter to bathe but he would not do it."

Comment: Why shouldn't "we" use those tenses? What tenses do you think "we" should use there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use present perfect to show a relation to the present. In this case, I would assume that either Peter is refusing to bathe right now, or that he has been refusing to bathe for some time, and has not bathed yet.

The *will* here is probably the *desire* will, and not the *future* will: Peter does not desire to bath, rather than Peter is not going to bathe. You can't use *would* here because this is not something that happened in the past.