# What's the difference between "won't" and "wouldn't"?

Tags: will-would

What's the difference between "I won't blame you" and "I wouldn't blame you"?

Comment: won't = will not. wouldn't = would not

Comment: @Sprottenwels Although, I agree that they could have done a little more research, keep in mind they asked the difference between the *statements*, not just the words. Maybe there is some confusion stemming from them that only a english language learner experiences.

Comment: @LamarLatrell I didn't mean to scold the OP for his laziness. It rather was all I could contribute to the question, hence I chose to do a brief comment :)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["won't" vs. "wouldn't"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20491/wont-vs-wouldnt)

Answer (score 2):

To my ear "I won't" is unconditional.

"I wouldn't" implies the possibility of unspoken/implied conditions:

> I wouldn't ... (*if* such and such conditions are upheld.)

I won't is a step closer to I *can't*.

Wouldn't is a potential step in the direction of weasel words.

Answer (score 0):

First is from will+not, second from would+not, as in:

I **will not** do it in a million years (ie. not a chance)

vs.

I **would not** do it if... (ie. there is some possibility).

That is at least my guess.

Answer (score -2):

both sentences are nearly the same.
The only difference between them is that would is sometimes used to give a more polite impression.

Source: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would (See the uses of would)

Regards

Comment: But from your own link, politeness is only one of several reasons one might use "would", and in fact the last one given. (And further, while I agree that we do sometimes use it for politeness, the example there is rather questionable.)