# What is the difference between the two sentences? (if clause)

Tags: meaning, differences

- If you were asked to describe yourself, what would you say?
- If you are asked to describe yourself, what will you say?

I understand that "if you are" and "if you were" are different.
but I would think that the two sentences I wrote above are practically the same or have no difference in meaning. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

**Let's look at the different types of conditional sentences to figure out what each sentence means.**

***Note: There are two clauses in a conditional sentence: the "if" clause and the main clause.  The main clause is the independent clause, whereas the "if" clause is dependent.***

*If you don't want to read the whole answer, scroll to the bottom to find the "main points."*

---

#### Type 0

This is used when the situation is *real/possible* and the main clause is *always true* when the "if" clause is true.  This is used for **general truths.**

Example:

> If you die, your heart stops.

The "if" clause uses the **simple present** tense, and the main clause also uses the **simple present** tense.

A trick to use to check if a sentence is of type 0 is to see if "if" and "when" can be used interchangeably; if they can be, then it is of type 0.

---

#### Type 1

***This is the type of conditional that your second sentence is.***

This is used when the situation is *possible* and the mains cause is *probable* when the "if" clause is true.  The sentence refers to the *present or future.*

Example:

> If you use profane language, the teacher will reprimand you.

The "if" clause uses the **simple present** tense, and the main clause uses the **simple future** tense.

Type 1 is distinct from type 0 because the result (main clause) of type 1 conditionals is *probable, but not guaranteed.*  In the above example for type 1 conditional, it is possible the teacher is out of earshot, so there is no guarantee that you will be reprimanded (or the teacher could simply be indifferent to the use of profane language).

---

#### Type 2

***This is the type of conditional that your first sentence is.***

This is used when the situation is *unrealistic* and the main clause is *probable* when the "if" clause is true.  The sentence refers to *any time.*

Examples:

> If I was confident, I wouldn't care about how I look.

and

> If I was confident, I would be wearing that bikini.

The "if" clause uses the **simple past** tense, and the main clause uses **the simple present conditional or the progressive present conditional** tense.  The simple/progressive present tenses are made conditional by adding a modal auxiliary verb (such as "would") to the main verb.

---

#### Type 3

This is used when the situation is *hypothetical* and in the *past;* the main clause *was probable, **but did not actually happen.***

Example:

> If I had fallen, I could have broken my arm.

and

> If I had fallen, I would have been airborne for a few seconds.

The "if" clause uses the **past perfect** tense, and the main clause uses the **perfect conditional or progressive perfect conditional** tense.  The perfect/progressive perfect tenses are made conditional by adding a modal auxiliary verb (such as "would") to the main verb.

---

**Now we can understand the subtle differences in their meanings.**

The **first** sentence, which falls under the category of type 2, **implies that *you will probably never be asked to describe yourself.***

The **second** sentence, which is type 1, **insinuates that *you will likely be asked this question in the future.***

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!  your answer will help.

Comment: @user393215 Thank you. I'm glad I was able to help! Please upvote and accept the answer so other users know that it is reputable; this will also prevent other users from drafting responses to a question that has already been answered.

Comment: Here's one more question.
A :  Please explain the concept of this drawing.
B : I wouldn't.
Which type is it? and what does "i wouldn't" mean?

Comment: @user393215 I see "I wouldn't" as "I would not [explain the concept]."  However, I would probably say "I won't" ("I will not [explain the concept]") instead.  Read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20491/wont-vs-wouldnt).

Comment: @user393215 I'm glad I was able to help! Please accept the answer so other users know that it is reputable; this will also prevent other users from drafting responses to a question that has already been answered.